# Solving a Recurence Relation with 2 parameters

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the following recurrence relation

$$u(n,1) = 1$$
$$u(1,m) = 1$$
$$u(n,m) = u(n-1, m) + u(n, m-1)$$

with $n > 0, m > 0$,

how can one end up with a closed formula, without using generating functions?

Comment: I'm assuming that $n$ and $m$ are positive integers, and the given recurrence is for $n,m\geqslant 2$?

Comment: @Math1000  thanks, I added this conditions

Comment: Do you have a background about solving recurrence equations?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Well I know some of the ad hoc approaches like, guess & induct, or subtracting r(i) form r(i+1) and going down to r(1) this way...

Comment: Why no generating functions?

Comment: @Did Because I was able to solve it using GF, but wanted to be able to solve it without too :)

Comment: "am I concluding correctly that there is no non-adhoc way of attacking such problems?" Incorrect, the non ad hoc way is to use generating functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compute $u(n,m)$ for e.g. $1\leqslant n,m\leqslant 6$ you should see a pattern. In particular, look at the diagonals where $n+m=k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$. I came up with

> $$\displaystyle u(n,m) = \binom{n+m}n,$$

which clearly satisfies the recurrence, as

> $$\displaystyle\binom{n+m}n = \binom{n+m-1}{n-1} + \binom{n+m-1}n.$$

Comment: Thank you, so am I concluding correctly that there is no non-adhoc way of attacking such problems?

Comment: Well, that is generally my approach when I don't know a method to solve a problem off-hand. It just so happened that for this problem, that worked. The other way to go about it would be to recognize the recurrence as the binomial coefficients, but I am not great at combinatorics so I didn't see that immediately.